# Facebook long lived access token error 191 redirect_uri

Tags: facebook, redirect, token

I am stuck on this one even though I've read thousands of things about it on google so you are my last resort:

Here is my java call:

```
RestTemplate facebookRestTemp = new RestTemplate();

Map<String, String> vars = new HashMap<String, String>();
vars.put("fb_exchange_token", authToken.getAuthToken());
vars.put("client_secret", "97597d5b491d3de002056f064ffd1afa");
vars.put("grant_type", "fb_exchange_token");
vars.put("client_id", "496902567150512");

Object result = facebookRestTemp.getForEntity("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token", Object.class, vars);
```

I get the error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Missing redirect_uri parameter.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 191,
    "fbtrace_id": "xxxx"
  }
}
```

In my app settings I've set:

[image] 
[image]

I've tried with replacing the `:`, `/` by their hex representation. Didn't work.

Does anyone of you have an idea?